# Elasticsearch custom file based analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 6 and have a full text field in the index. This field stores the category of a product and can take only one of few possible values(e.g fruit, leafy vegetables etc). I want to analyse the field in a custom way with tokens specified in a file.
E.g

fresh fruit->[fruit, fresh fruit]

Is there a way to use a custom analyser with final tokens coming from a mapping file as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [synonym token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html). You need to create a custom analyser which used this filter so that when input string is `fresh fruit` or `fruit` then it generates single token `fruit`. You can achieve this by defining analysis in index settings. Create a custom analyser that uses the filter and then apply that analyser to the `category` field as below:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_synonym_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "custom_synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "custom_synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "fresh fruit, fruit => fruit"
            ],
            //"synonyms_path": "analysis/synonyms.txt"    <---- replace "synonyms" above with this to use file instead of array of synonyms
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "category": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_synonym_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now when you search for either `fruit` or `fresh fruit` against `category` field documents with either `fruit` or `fresh fruit` will match. This is because when searching against a field elastic search by default uses same analyzer on the search string that was applied on the the field while indexing, which in this case will eventually boils down to `fruit` in either case (`fruit` or `fresh fruit`) and hence the documents will match.

Comment: Thanks for the approach, this can certainly work. If, say I have to add new mappings to the synonyms file, then does it require closing-opening of index? OR reindexing?

Comment: In that case you will have to restart the nodes.

Comment: @SauravPrakash Did this solved your problem? If yes please feel free to accept and upvote.